# How to upgrade debian (no network or direct access)

Tags: debian, upgrade, iso-image

I'am running debian 4.0 on machine with no internet access. How can I upgrade it to latest stable? I can download iso using local machine and upload it via scp.
whats next? Which iso - is cd1 enough or need download big dvd? 
Machine is running apache + php, no other extra packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need mount this ISO image:

```
  $ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/iso /mnt/deb-cd1
```

Next add **/mnt/deb-cd1** to **/etc/apt/sources.list**:

```
deb file:///mnt/deb-cd1 squeeze main contrib
```

Next run:

```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**NOTE**: As CD can not contain all the packages that you installed in your system some packages will be preserved with old versions... Using DVD you can upgrade more packages then by CD.

CD contains a new kernel, libc and build toolset (as well as new Perl/Python/Ruby) so it is enough to upgrade. But namy other software that you can use out of CD content.

**NOTE** Debiand 4.0 is too old and is not maintained now. So there are no any security fixes.

Comment: Thanks. I want all new packages. As I said it is running apache+php+mysql application, I want to keep running it after upgrade.
Im developer, linux begginer, inherited this server and want to ugrade  it so can install latest java.

Comment: :( - sth wrong : downloaded **debian-6.0.2.1-i386-CD-1.iso** and followed steps.  
  
during apt-get update got error :  cant download file file:///mnt/deb-cd1/dists/squeeze/contrib/binary-i386/Packages.gz)  

         
    `mantis:/mnt/deb-cd1/dists/squeeze/contrib/binary-i386# ls`
    `Release'

Comment: ok, removed `contrib` from sources.list, and now successed this step

Comment: Last time I use only DVD and there are exist **contrib**. **non-free** not allowed for distribution on CD/DVD.